# How would I center an entry in the table of contents and suppress the page number entry?

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

In my table of contents, I would like to suppress the page number entries for parts, and center the entry, as follows:

[image: Desired output]

My attempt at it does not go as planned. Here is my MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}

\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\centering} % to have something centered to commpare it to
\renewcommand*{\cftpartname}{\partname\space}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartaftersnum}{.\space}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartformatpnum}[1]{}  %suppress the page number entry
\renewcommand\partnumberlinebox[2]{\hfill#2\hfill}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*
\part{Lorem ipsum}
\chapter{Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt}
\chapter{Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua}
\part{Consectetur adipiscing elit}
\chapter{Cras ornare arcu dui vivamus}
\chapter{Arcu felis bibendum}

\end{document}
```

And here is what it looks like:

[image: Current output]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code. (two lines added)

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\centering} % to have something centered to commpare it to
\renewcommand*{\cftpartname}{\partname\space}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartaftersnum}{.\space}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartformatpnum}[1]{}  %suppress the page number entry

%\renewcommand\partnumberlinebox[2]{\hfill#2\hfill}% not needed
\renewcommand*{\cftpartfont}{\hfill\large\bfseries}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<
\renewcommand*{\cftpartafterpnum}{\hfill}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents*
    \part{Lorem ipsum}
    \chapter{Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt}
    \chapter{Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua}
    \part{Consectetur adipiscing elit}
    \chapter{Cras ornare arcu dui vivamus}
    \chapter{Arcu felis bibendum}
    
\end{document}
```

How does it work:

This is a simplified pseudo-code version for the typesetting of (part) numbered  entries. (memoir manual, page 155, section 9.2)

```
{\cftpartfont {{\cftpartname \cftpartpresnum SNUM\cftpartaftersnum\hfil} \cftpartaftersnumb TITLE}}{\cftpartleader}{\cftpartformatpnum{PAGE}}\cftpartafterpnum\par
```

so new lines add `\hfill` to the beginning and end of the entry to center it.

These are their default definitions:

```
\newcommand{\cftpartfont}{\large\bfseries}
\newcommand{\cftpartafterpnum}{}
```