# Why does the microtype package shift the centering in a memoir-altered table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, microtype

I created a table of contents that centers the parts and suppresses the page number entry. (See [How would I center an entry in the table of contents and suppress the page number entry?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/675367/how-would-i-center-an-entry-in-the-table-of-contents-and-suppress-the-page-numbe/))

**Update 1:** I use TexLive 2022 (MacTeX) on Apple Silicon. `pdfLaTeX`, `XeLaTeX`, and `LuaLaTeX` all produce the same results.

**Update 2:** It seems as though `\dotfill` produces the same (bad) result regardless of whether `microtype` is used or not. I have edited my MWE to use `\hfill`.

**Update 3:** I just tried this on Overleaf, which allows experimenting with different versions of TexLive. This seems to be a problem only in TexLive 2022 (i.e., in TexLive 2021 and earlier, it doesn’t happen).

However, when I add the `microtype` package, it shifts the centering to the left. Why does `microtype` do this? Is there a work-around?

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{microtype}  % Comment out to restore correct behavior

\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\centering}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartname}{\partname\space}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartaftersnum}{.\space}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartformatpnum}[1]{}  %suppress the page number
\renewcommand*{\cftpartfont}{\hfill{}\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartafterpnum}{\hfill}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*
\part{Lorem ipsum}
\chapter{Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt}
\chapter{Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua}
\part{Consectetur adipiscing elit}
\chapter{Cras ornare arcu dui vivamus}
\chapter{Arcu felis bibendum}

\end{document}
```

Current output (note how it is not aligned with the contents title):
[image: Current output]

Desired output:
[image: Desired output]

Comment: You might want to edit the title :-)

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: @IanThompson, TexLive 2022 (that is, MacTex). Interesting. I will test it elsewhere.

Comment: I see no difference with or without `microtype`. Perhaps you should add images of both. I don't quite understand what you are trying to do with the design.

Comment: @daleif, I will add that, but in the meantime, follow the link to my earlier question.

Comment: try loading microtype with the option `nopatch=toc`

Comment: It will work if you remove the line `\renewcommand{\cftpartafterpnum}{\hfill}` when adding `microtype`. (I do not know why). The file .toc does not change. It  is related with the way memoir typesets the TOC.

Comment: @Robert, that did it. @SimonDispa, I think `microtype` (or some weird interaction between `microtype` and `memoir`) is inserting an `\hfill` on the right, which would explain why your fix works.

Comment: you want to add `\renewcommand*{\cftpartleader}{}`, which cancels the leader between the title and the (suppressed) page number. This solves both problems (with `\dotfill` and with microtype), so that you don't need to load microtype with the nopatch option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experimenting, I think I have found the best solution.

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}

% Apparently, the latest version of microtype interferes
% with the dot leader macro. However, we can disable that macro.
\usepackage{microtype}  

% Have something centered for comparison
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\centering}

% Format the part name and number
\renewcommand*{\cftpartname}{\partname\space}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartaftersnum}{.\space}

% Suppress the page number
\renewcommand*{\cftpartformatpnum}[1]{}

% Disable the dot leader code entirely
\renewcommand*{\cftpartleader}{}

% Dissolve the linebox (otherwise, the part title
% is slightly off-center)
\renewcommand*{\partnumberlinebox}[2]{#2}

% Set the font and add the \hfill commands
\renewcommand*{\cftpartfont}{\large\bfseries\hfill}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartafterpnum}{\large\bfseries\hfill}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*
\part{Lorem ipsum}
\chapter{Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt}
\chapter{Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua}
\part{Consectetur adipiscing elit}
\chapter{Cras ornare arcu dui vivamus}
\chapter{Arcu felis bibendum}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: Output]